# Why shouldComponentUpdate hook is not working in React?

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

I have started learning `react.js` and in its lifecycle, I got this `shouldComponentUpdate` method. And in return, I'm passing `false` still it affects dom. And in my reference video it's not affecting to the dom.

**Above render()**

```
shouldComponentUpdate ( nextProps, nextState ) {
    console.log( 'In shouldComponentUpdate', nextProps, nextState );        
    return false;
}
```

I'm using this version : `"react": "^16.9.0",`

Comment: man, it works if react detects some changes in your nextProp, nextState. In body your shouldComponentUpdate  we compare old prop with new one, or old state with new input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle fire ups on every component render.

In your case, if you want it to log something, you need to make component render, via its father (rendering the father so it render its children) or via self renders, for example changing its state:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = { counter: 0 };
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log('In shouldComponentUpdate', nextProps, nextState);
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlexBox>
        <Button onClick={() => this.setState({ counter: this.counter + 1 })}>
          Counter
        </Button>
      </FlexBox>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Q-57871306-ShouldComponentUpdate]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, This same thing is happening in my code also. I think it may be something else. In some way it's calling render() method that's why I got dom changes even I'm returning false.

Comment: It may cause due to father render, you should ask another question and provide a better example (whole code)

Comment: For example, if the component's container renders, it's render function called and within it all lifecycle of your component may restart/update

Answer (score 0):

During an update, `shouldComponentUpdate` is called before the render method is. It tells the component if it needs to re-render. And if `shouldComponentUpdate` returns false, the component is not re-rendered.

In your case,

```
shouldComponentUpdate ( nextProps, nextState ) {
    console.log( 'In shouldComponentUpdate', nextProps, nextState );        
    return false;
}
```

The `console.log` is triggered, but since you are returning false, the component wont re-render after that.

You can check it from the example here:

[image: Edit zen-ramanujan-3z1zh]

The count doesn't increment when you return false in `componentShouldUpdate` and increments when you return true.